# How come multiprocessing.Value isn't safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```py
# src/test.py
import multiprocessing as mp
n = mp.Value('i', 0, lock=True)

def foo(n):
    for i in range(10000):
        n.value += 1

processes = []
for i in range(2):
    p = mp.Process(target=foo, args=[n])
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

print(n.value)
```

```
$ python3 src/test.py 
17342
$ python3 src/test.py 
18485
$ python3 src/test.py 
12455
```

I thought the purpose of `multiprocessing.Value` (over `multiprocessing.RawValue`) was that it had a lock that made it thread safe. How come it gives me different results?

Comment: It's giving different result's because you're giving it different values. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question. You left out the expected results therefore my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value):

> Operations like `+=` which involve a read and write are not atomic. So if, for instance, you want to atomically increment a shared value it is insufficient to just do
>
> ```
> counter.value += 1
> ```
>
> Assuming the associated lock is recursive (which it is by default) you can instead do
>
> ```
> with counter.get_lock():
>     counter.value += 1
> ```